# Send message from service after api get

Tags: angular, typescript

My post.service receives a message via a MessageService from my area.service that I have set up to receive subjects as any type.
I am trying to convey the response of area.service to post.service via message.service.
The post service url should be http://localhost:8000/areas/fun/
The area service should be sending "fun".

post.service

```
    import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
        import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
        import { Observable, Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
        import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

        import { AuthenticationService, AreaService, MessageService} from './index';
        import { Post, Area} from '../_models/index';

        @Injectable()
        export class PostService implements OnDestroy {
          areas: Area[] = [];
          subject:Subject<Post[]> = new Subject();
          message: any;
       subscription: Subscription;
            constructor(
                private http: Http,
                private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
                private areaService: AreaService,
                private messageService: MessageService
              ) {
                this.subscription = this.messageService.getMessage().subscribe(message => { this.message = message;});
            }

            getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
              this.areaService.getAreas();

            // add authorization header with jwt token
            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Authorization','token ' + this.authenticationService.token);

            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          let options = new RequestOptions({

          headers: headers
        });

            // get posts from api
            return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/areas/'+ this.message.text +'/', options)
                .map((response: Response) => response.json());

        }
        ngOnDestroy() {
            // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
            this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
      }
```

area.service

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    import { AuthenticationService, MessageService } from './index';
    import { Area } from '../_models/index';

    @Injectable()
    export class AreaService {
      public areas: Area[] = [];
      public currentArea: string = "fun";
        constructor(
            private http: Http,
            private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
          private messageService: MessageService) {
        }

        getAreas(): void {
            // add authorization header with jwt token
            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Authorization','token ' + this.authenticationService.token);

            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          let options = new RequestOptions({
          headers: headers
          });

            // get areas from api
             this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/areas/', options)
                .map((response: Response) => {

                  this.areas = response.json();
                  this.messageService.sendMessage(this.areas[0].name);

                });
    //this.messageService.sendMessage(this.areas[0].name);
        }
    }
```

message.service

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

    @Injectable()
    export class MessageService {
        private subject = new Subject<any>();

        sendMessage(message: any) {
            this.subject.next({ text: message });
        }

        clearMessage() {
            this.subject.next();
        }

        getMessage(): Observable<any> {
            return this.subject.asObservable();
        }
    }
```

The error it is telling me is "Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined"

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: in your `PostService()`, there is no property called `message`. Hence `this.message` is undefined

Comment: It is here: message: any; it is not a problem with post.service it is a problem with area.service. once I get data via the area api call it should be sent to post.service as a string. this.messageService.sendMessage(this.currentArea); works in area.service but I think the area.service api call is wrong somehow

Comment: How do you use your service in your component? how do you call getPosts() ? are you subscribing to PostService.subscription?

Comment: Again its not a problem with subscribing, it is a problem in area.service. for some reason I can't pass the string from the Json array

Comment: @CameronGilbert, even you have the property, you did not initialized it. You need to do `this.message = something` in your constructor.

Comment: Still undefined